# MessageLevel in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, python-3, logging

I am trying to migrate a plugin to QGIS 3 from QGIS 2 and I am having issues with an API.

The original Python has `QgsMessageBar.MessageLevel` but https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html says it has been moved to `Qgis::MessageLevel`. I tried replacing it in the code and got an invalid syntax and I couldn't find a `MessageLevel` example in Python 3.

What does it mean when something has been moved to `Qgis::...`? How do I find the proper syntax and use?

Comment: which syntax did u try so far ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a util function like this

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis

def showUserMessage(before, text="", level=Qgis.Info, duration=3):
    ''' Show user info/warning/error messages '''
    iface.messageBar().popWidget()
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(before, text, level=level, duration=duration)

showUserMessage("Info : ", "Info Sample")
showUserMessage("Warning : ", "Warning Sample", Qgis.Warning)
showUserMessage("Critical : ", "Critical Sample", Qgis.Critical)
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me moving on to the next error...

Answer (score 5):

The proper syntax is like below:

```py
# First import Qgis class
from qgis.core import Qgis

...

def something():
    # Then you have to use like 'Qgis.MessageLevel' (Qgis.Info as an example)
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(text, level=Qgis.Info)
```

For more information, please review [Communicating with the user](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html) and [QGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a60c079f4d8b7c479498be3d42ec96257).

Comment: Both answers are really close and got me going again; I accepted Fran Raga as the answer because that one simply looked more like the code I was working with so I figured out what needed to change. Now that I see the changes I can see just how similar these 2 answers are...