# Getting readable message level of Qgis.MessageLevel

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, logging, qgis.core

I have an instance of https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.MessageLevel, e.g.

```py
level = Qgis.Info
```

I want to get a human-readable string like *"Info"* or *"Qgis.Info"* from this object.

- `print(level)` prints `0`
  `str(level)` returns `0`
- `type(level)` returns `<class 'qgis._core.Qgis.MessageLevel'>`

Is there a straightforward way to get a human-readable string representation of the `MessageLevel` object's level?

I am not looking for an `if` clause checking the integer value against the known values but if that is all that would be possible, a explanatory and canonical "no" would be a good answer.

Comment: Can be also useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317190/messagelevel-in-qgis3

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware PyQt does not support iteration over names/values of Qt's enum types as you could do with standard python enums.

Instead, you can get information on the enumerator via the `staticMetaObject` of the class which contains the enum. In this case `Qgis`.

```
idx = Qgis.staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator(Qgis.MessageLevel.__name__)
name = Qgis.staticMetaObject.enumerator(idx).valueToKey(Qgis.Info)

print(name) # prints 'Info'
```

Answer (score 2):

They are a few functions having `displayString` in their name to convert an enum item to a "display string".

Like  https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html#a74a5669aeb2975d4079656202c5ed5d9

For `MessageLevel`, there isn't any such function in https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html or other classes, as I could checked.

So no, it's not possible AFAIK with the QGIS API. Maybe someone will come with a deeper core Python function with the inspection module ?

Answer (score 1):

With pure Python, you can do introspection and create your own useful translator :

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis

message_levels = {
    getattr(Qgis, i): i for i in dir(Qgis)
    if isinstance(getattr(Qgis, i), Qgis.MessageLevel)
}
# {0: 'Info', 1: 'Warning', 2: 'Critical', 3: 'Success', 4: 'NoLevel'}
```

So, in your usecase :

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis

level = Qgis.Info
print(message_levels[level])
# >>> Info
```

Comment: The `message_levels` can most likely not be sorted, so check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: The question here is about the readable message level, I just created a Python dict that transforms Qgis.MessageLevel into readable text. And the dict works without being sorted.

Comment: I know ^_^ Maybe it simply did not work in my case

Comment: sorted levels : `{k: message_levels[k] for k in sorted(message_levels)}`